# SQL query to check if a date is close to today

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, date

Here's a table:

`orders(id, item, deliveryDate, courier_id)`

I'd like to write a query that will return all orders for a given courier with a delivery date that's within a month of today. How do I do that?

Comment: What database? And have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I believe it's going to depend on which DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In T-SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE deliveryDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 30
  AND courier_id = @CourierID
```

---

**EDIT**

While the period in this solution is calculated to be roughly a month, it is not precisely one month, as *uncle brad* has neatly observed. If you need to be precise, you should calculate one month from the current date like this: `DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())`. This replaces `GETDATE() + 30` in the above query.

Comment: Not every month has 30 days.  You should use `dateadd(MONTH,1,getdate())` in place of `getdate() + 30`.

Comment: @uncle brad: Not necessarily I should. If, for example, I wanted to represent data as a chart showing for each day how many deliveries are scheduled in the coming period, it would seem to me to make more sense if the period was fixed. Still, your point is valid, as we actually don't know the requirements for this case, so I've updated my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most servers use the integer part of the date for days.

In this example I use "Now()" as a server function that returns the current date.
You should look the right one on the documentation of the server you use.

(also the ? mark as the value of courier id)

```
Select * 
From orders
Where Now() - deliveryDate < 30
And courier_id = ?
```

If your server does not hold days - you can look on it's date-conversion functions

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL

[DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE deliveryDate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```